# Как выгрузить свойство раздела из 1с?

Tags: битрикс, 1с

При импорте битрикса, есть возможность импортировать свойства раздела в структуру сайта в формате (в файле xml):

```
<Группы>
        <Группа>
            <Ид>40a1ea23-db7d-4040-9fd2-c2ee4c742ckk</Ид>
            <НомерВерсии>123</НомерВерсии>
            <ПометкаУдаления>false</ПометкаУдаления>
            <Наименование>Тетради</Наименование>
            <ЗначенияСвойств>
                <ЗначенияСвойства>
                    <Ид>UF_NAME</Ид>
                    <Значение>Другое имя</Значение>
                </ЗначенияСвойства>
                <ЗначенияСвойства>
                    <Ид>UF_DESCRIPTION</Ид>
                    <Значение>Другое описание</Значение>
                </ЗначенияСвойства>
            </ЗначенияСвойств>
        </Группа>
    </Группы>
```

Тут параметры `<ЗначенияСвойств> ... </ЗначенияСвойств>` я дописал вручную.
Где в структуре номенклатуры можно дописать эти свойства и как их выгружать на сайт?

Comment: Свойства номенклатуры при интеграции с 1С будут выгружены в свойства инфоблока автоматически. Дополнительно вы можете в настройках модуля обмена указать какие свойства нужно выгружать.

Comment: @NikolajSarry  это будут свойства товаров/торг.предложений, я говорю о разделах

Comment: Все понял. Тут только один выход, переписать модуль обмен таким образом, чтобы при выгрузке свойства раздела считались свойством товара. Думаю в 1С не сложно сделать такую обработку. По другому не сделаете никак.